# Войти в аккаунт юзера discord. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я создаю бота, который помогает людям за них писать некоторые сообщения в discord.

Я бы хотел зайти в аккаунт пользователя discord через js скрипт.

Возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.